# Probability input XGBOST R

Tags: r, xgboost

I am using XGBoost algorith with R. I know that with the parameter **objective = 'multi:softprob'** it returns a probability of the predicted value to be in each class.

In addition, I want to enter the labels of the model as probabilities too. I was searching and I did not found anything. Someone know if that is possible?

Here is the code that I have to try that:

```
#Create Random data
X <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,6,rep=TRUE)))
X$X1 <- as.numeric(X$X1)
X$X2 <- as.numeric(X$X2)
Y1 = matrix(c(1,1,0,1,0,1),nrow=6, ncol=1) 
Y2 = matrix(c(0.1,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.9,0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9,0.1,0.1,0.9),nrow=6, ncol=2) 

#First model
xgb1 <- xgboost(data = data.matrix(X), 
               label = Y1,
               eta = 0.1,
               max_depth = 15, 
               nround=25, 
               subsample = 0.5,
               colsample_bytree = 0.5,
               seed = 1,
               eval_metric = "merror",
               objective = "multi:softprob",
               num_class = 2,
               nthread = 3
)
predict(xgb1, data.matrix(X[1,]))

#Desired model
xgb <- xgboost(data = data.matrix(X), 
               label = Y2,
               eta = 0.1,
               max_depth = 15, 
               nround=25, 
               subsample = 0.5,
               colsample_bytree = 0.5,
               seed = 1,
               eval_metric = "merror",
               objective = "multi:softprob",
               num_class = 2,
               nthread = 3
)
```

The first model is the one I'm used to, and the second one is something like the model I want. The only diference is the label format but I don't know if the second option is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code and explain what you expect and what actually happens.

Comment: Done! Sorry I never posted here before